# Calculate average of columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, rating

Below is my table (`tblReviewRating`) with data:

```
rrFood    rrService    rrCleanliness    rrAmbience    rrBqtID    rrCusID
------    ---------    -------------    ----------    -------    -------
3         4            2                1             1          1
5         4            3                2             1          2
4         2            4                2             2          5
4         2            4                2             2          7
4         2            4                2             2          9
```

I'm trying to calculate the average of first four columns (out of 5 scale) of each separate banquet hall (`rrBqtID`) from the customers (`rrCusID`):

```
SELECT rrFood,rrService,rrCleanliness,rrAmbience, 
       ROUND(AVG(rrFood+rrService+rrCleanliness+rrAmbience),2) AS AverageRating 
FROM tblReviewRating
GROUP BY rrFood,rrService,rrCleanliness,rrAmbience
```

How I can calculate the average rating of four services and average of `AverageRating` for every banquet hall given by their customers?

**Edited:**
I want to apply [this example](https://blog.cognitoforms.com/3-easy-ways-to-calculate-rating-scales-1) in my query to calculate rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the avg for rrBqtID, rrCusID  you should group by for rrFood,rrService,rrCleanliness,rrAmbience but for rrBqtID, rrCusID

```
SELECT rrBqtID, rrCusID, 
       ROUND(AVG(rrFood+rrService+rrCleanliness+rrAmbience),2) AS AverageRating 
FROM tblReviewRating
GROUP BY rrBqtID, rrCusID
```

And if you want see the avg near other infor you should use a join eg;

```
SELECT A.rrFood,A.rrService,A.rrCleanliness,A.rrAmbience , T.AverageRating
FROM tblReviewRating A
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT rrBqtID, rrCusID, 
           ROUND(AVG(rrFood+rrService+rrCleanliness+rrAmbience),2) AS AverageRating 
    FROM tblReviewRating
    GROUP BY rrBqtID, rrCusID
) T ON T.rrBqtID = A.rrBqtID and T.rrCusID = A.rrCusID
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not `group by` the `column`s you are aggregating with, but by the `column`s you want to `group by`. So, instead of grouping by `rrFood`, `rrService`, `rrCleanliness`, `rrAmbience`, you should `group by` `rrBqtID` and `rrCustID`, respectively.

And you can get the average of four `column`s by using the formula of

**(column1 + column2 + column3 + column4) / 4**

and then aggregate this, using `AVG`:

```
select rrBqtID, rrCustID, AVG(AverageRating) as AverageRating
from
(SELECT rrBqtID, rrCustID, ROUND(rrFood+rrService+rrCleanliness+rrAmbience) / 4,2) AS AverageRating 
FROM tblReviewRating) t
group by rrBqtID, rrCustID
```

Comment: @Asif.Ali I have edited my answer. Do you still see an error?

Comment: @Asif.Ali I have edited my answer. Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you see the average ratings of each banquet hall. hope this helps.

```
SELECT rrBqtID, AVG(rrFood) AS AVGrrFood,AVG(rrService) AS AVGrrService,AVG(rrCleanliness) AS AVGrrCleanliness,AVG(rrAmbience) AS AVGrrAmbience, 
   ROUND(AVG((rrFood+rrService+rrCleanliness+rrAmbience)/4),2) AS AverageRating 
FROM tblReviewRating
GROUP BY rrBqtID
```

Comment: i worked but how to calculate avg of `AverageRating`.

Comment: try GROUP BY ROLLUP(rrBqtID) and see if it is what you needed.

Comment: The ROLLUP gives additional row at the bottom; the overall average. not what you looking for?